# XSL-FO, align two blocks in a table cell

Tags: xsl-fo

I have the following XSL code and what I want to achieve is to have the headline aligned to the top of the cell and the description to the bottom of the cell:

```
<fo:table-cell>                        
    <fo:block display-align="before">
        <xsl:value-of select="headline" />
    </fo:block>
    <fo:block display-align="after">
        <xsl:value-of select="description" />                            
    </fo:block>
</fo:table-cell>
```

I don't know why, but it doesn't seem to work for all the cells in the table.

Can this code be improved so the transformation can happen to all cells?

Comment: The property `display-align` applies to `fo:table-cell` (and other formatting objects) but **not** to `fo:block`. Can you use two rows instead (one for headlines, one for the descriptions)? What formatter are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best solution, as suggested by Ifurini, would be to split your table-cell into two rows. If that's not what you want, try this:

```
<fo:table table-layout="fixed">
    <fo:table-column/>
    <fo:table-body line-height="16pt">
        <fo:table-row height="100pt">
            <fo:table-cell>
                <fo:block-container height="50pt" display-align="before">
                    <fo:block>Top</fo:block>    
                </fo:block-container>
                <fo:block-container height="50pt" display-align="after">
                    <fo:block >Bottom</fo:block>    
                </fo:block-container>
            </fo:table-cell>
        </fo:table-row>
    </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

So use `display-align` inside a `block-conainer`. But you would have to give some kind of height-constraints otherwise the container just wraps its content, leaving `display-align` useless.